# My Shortlink Service Count More Hits Then Google Analytics. How Is This Possible?

Tags: nginx, log-files

I have created a simple shortlink service that does a 301 redirection just like Bitly. Rather than storing each visitor hit on a db on a redirection, I am simply analyzing Nginx's access log files to figure out how many hits I get per each redirection.

First, I have used my own parser to analyze access logs and saw that my hit count were at least 3x-5x larger than GA. Even if I counted only distinct IP addresses, my hit counts were always bigger than GA. I thought something was wrong with my log parser so I switched to GoAccess to analyze access logs but got very similiar results.

When doing my analysis, I have compared the clicks I got from Facebook insights to redirected url in GA analytics. Facebook's count and GA's count seems to overlap. However, hits on my access logs are way bigger.

I know that visitor information in log files can be misleading and inaccurate. I put cloudflare in front of my shortlink domain to minimize attacks and trim some of the bad traffic. Maybe using Cloudlfare might be a bad idea. However, at the end of the day I don't think there should be 3x-5x difference on each url I redirect.

Can you guys please tell me what I am doing wrong here ? How does services like Bitly count hits ? Should I abondon access logs ?

Thank you.

Comment: For a start GA will not run if people block browser scripts etc etc. There are so many variables.

Comment: I am using my shortlinks only on Facebook and I am comparing Facebook insights's clicks with Google Analytics's sessions and they do match. But my logs are way off. How is this possible ?

Comment: That is completely different to what your questions states... Please update your question.

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope its more clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is based on browser scripts. You may find that certain browser add-ins may be blocking the GA script. Also some Corporations block GA at the firewall level.

Also Google only tracks humans, (they do display web crawlers) Also things like external styles and scripts will show up in your logs.

CloudFlare have a good [article](https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/google_analytics/) on this  on how to integrate it using there built in APP.

Comment: Hi. I strip out crawlers in my logs but still Nginx log hits are way off.